# Search on Ehcache Element

Tags: ehcache

I have list object(List that is in cache,Is anyone knows how to do search on that 
list object withehcache api.Please give me any samples.

Thanks in Advance --Raju

Answer (score 0):

Search has only been introduced in Ehcache 2.4 (which is still beta as of today).

You can get the beta here : http://terracotta.org/beta/

and a sample app using Search here : https://github.com/sharrissf/Ehcache-Search-Sample/downloads